# After creating Archieve file in Xcode why it shows the validation error signing identities?

Tags: xcode, itunes-store

[Click to see the error snapshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muUvQ.png)

While launching app on iTunes store , After achieving the file thru Xcode  and validation it shows the error about signing identities.why? Any one send me the appropriate solution please.

[xcode snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJEHu.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have a valid certificate, however you haven't downloaded it or told Xcode to use it.  Update it using the [instructions given by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html) and Xcode should avoid attempting to generate a certificate.

Comment: how please elaborate

Comment: Now it work perfectly.Actually my Apple certificate has expired thats why. @trojanfoe